# How to get min,max,mean and Standard deviation in this case?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I built an R shiny app.The data is supposed to load confidential data for my company and dynamiccaly plot multiple plots stacked over each others.You can see how some statistics can not be calculated though the column exist and how "coord_cartesian(ylim = range(mydf()$par))" was detected and worked .[image]

```
 observe({
    req(input$Parmeter)
    lapply(input$Parmeter, function(par){

 

p1<-ggplot(mydf(), aes_string(x ="Lot",y = par,group=1)) +
        geom_point(size=2,colour="#007A9D",shape=4)+
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+
        theme(
          
          axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = "#007A9D"),
          axis.title.y.left  = element_text(color = "#007A9D")
          
        )
p2 <- ggplot(mydf(), aes_string(y = par)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 2) +
  labs(y = NULL) 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = range(mydf()$par))

 

p3 <- ggplot(mydf()) +
  theme_void() +
  annotate(
    geom = "label",
    x = 0, y = .5,
    label = paste(
      "Mean = ", round(mean(mydf()$par), 1), "\n",
      "sigma = ", round(sd(mydf()$par), 1),"\n",
      "Min = ", round(min(mydf()$par), 1),"\n",
      "Max = ", round(max(mydf()$par), 1),"\n",
      "Cp/k = ", round(max(mydf()$par), 1)
    ),
    hjust = 0
  ) 
 

 


      
      
      output[[paste("plot", par, sep = "_")]] <- renderPlot({
        p3 + p1 + p2 +
          plot_layout(widths = c(1, 3, 1))
      },
      width = 1800,
      height = 350)
      

 


}
)
    

 


  })
```

I foget to mention these are the errors i am getting (i am convinced about them since the column exist and has no zero length):

```
Warning in min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in mean.default(mydf()$par) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
Warning in min(mydf()$par) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(mydf()$par) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in max(mydf()$par) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: Well, as `par` contains the name of a column in your dataset `mydf()` try with `mydf()[[par]]` instead of using `...$par` as the latter will look for a column named `"par"` and will most likely return NULL.

Comment: @stefan Thank you for the wonderful answer .It was the right solution!!